# JQuery,animate() - как сделать анимированный блок

Tags: jquery

Дело таково что надо сделать рекламный блок который движется снизу на вверх и исчезает, затем опять появляется снизу и так до бесконечности.

Вот html:

```
<ul class="ads-list">
    <div>
       <li><a href="">РЕКЛАМА - ЭТО ХОРОШО</a></li>
    </div>                                      
</ul>
```

А вот JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".ads-list > div").animate({
                  marginTop:"150px", //Сделал вот так, а дальше голова не варит
                  } ,800)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Решение без JS.

А вы уверены, что нужно обязательно использовать JS? Есть простой способ делать анимацию на чистом CSS:

```css
@keyframes my_animation {
  0% {
    margin-top: 100vh;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0%
  }
}
.ads-list > div {
  animation: my_animation 5s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ads-list">
  <div>
     <li><a href="">РЕКЛАМА - ЭТО ХОРОШО</a>
     </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

А лучше через `transform`:

```css
@keyframes my_animation {
  0% {
       transform: translateY(100vh);
  }
  100% {
       transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.ads-list > div {
  animation: my_animation 5s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ads-list">
  <div>
     <li><a href="">РЕКЛАМА - ЭТО ХОРОШО</a>
     </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: `margin` это одно из самых плохих свойств по производительности для анимации. Лучше все анимировать при помощи `transform`.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko Хорошо, добавил в ответ

Comment: а можно сделать так, чтобы блок при достижении верхнего края появился снизу. А то тут он просто исчезает(не интересно так) заранее Спасибо! :)

Comment: аа все я понял как надо сделать) Надо просто transform: translateY(100vh); по выше сделать  ) спс за ответ

Answer (score 2):

если надо в другую сторону, просто задайте начальную позицию елементу а движение обратно

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var a = window.innerHeight;

    $(".ads-list > div").animate({
      marginTop: a,
    }, 800/*Длительность самой анимации в ms*/, function(){
     $(this).css({
        marginTop: 0,
      });
    })
  }, 1500); // интервал через которий будет повторятса анимация в ms
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ads-list">
  <div>
    <li><a href="">РЕКЛАМА - ЭТО ХОРОШО</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

C низу в верх

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var a = window.innerHeight;

    $(".ads-list > div").animate({
      marginTop: 0,
    }, 800/*Длительность самой анимации в ms*/, function(){
     $(this).css({
        marginTop: a,
      });
    })
  }, 1500); // интервал через которий будет повторятса анимация в ms
})
```

```css
div {
  marginTop: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ads-list">
  <div>
    <li><a href="">РЕКЛАМА - ЭТО ХОРОШО</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```